# pthread_cond_timedwait returns EPERM in FreeBSD

Tags: c, pthreads, freebsd

I have a code base which works on other Linux platforms, like CentOS, Redhat,...
But it failed in my FreeBSD 10.1 release version.
What I have here is a monitor handler, it does then same thing every 10sec.

It's normal at the first few times, it return 60 (timeout) so the monitor_handler keeps running. But when it return 1 (Operation not permitted), the handler will stop and be lock at pthread_mutex_lock.

I try removing getOSName() and just print some value from the handler, the handler can keep running. But I'm not sure if it just the time problem, maybe it will fail after more days.

I also try not using popen in getOSName(), it could run longer but still will hang. But the ret is 60 (timeout) and hang after pthread_mutex_lock.

Do anyone have idea about these three situations? Is there a bug in FreeBSD for this function or I can't use it like this way.
Are there other methods I can implement the wait and lock in FreeBSD?

Thanks.

=========update full code for reproduce====================

```
    pthread_t monitor_thread;
    pthread_mutex_t monitor_lock;
    pthread_cond_t monitor_condition;

int start() {
    if (getServiceCount() > 0) {
        printf("service existed\n");
        printErrLog(" ", "service existed");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (initIni() == EXIT_FAILURE)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);


    struct sigaction act;
    //signal terminate call back
    memset(&act, '\0', sizeof(act));
    act.sa_sigaction = &signal_callback_handler;
    act.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sigaction(SIGTERM, &act, NULL);
    skeleton_daemon();      
    _init_mutex();

    mStatus = 1;
    getTASInfo();


    if (initThread() == EXIT_FAILURE)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void skeleton_daemon() {
    pid_t pid;

    pid = fork();

    if (pid < 0) {
        printf("fork failed!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    //printf("file name %s\n", pidFile);
    if (pid > 0) {
        //printf("pid = %d\n", pid);

        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }

    umask(0);

    if (setsid() < 0) {
        printf("set sid failed!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (chdir("/") < 0) {
        printf("change to root directory failed!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int x;

    for (x = sysconf(_SC_OPEN_MAX); x > 0; x--) {
        close(x);
    }

}

int initThread() {
    int err;

    if (pthread_mutex_init(&monitor_lock, NULL) != 0) {
        printf("\n mutex init failed\n");
        printErrLog("initThread ", "monitor mutex init failed");
        return(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (pthread_cond_init(&monitor_condition, NULL) != 0) {
        printf("\n condition init failed\n");
        printErrLog("initThread ", "monitor condition init failed");
        return(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    err = pthread_create(&monitor_thread, NULL, (void *)&monitor_handler, NULL);

    if (err != 0) {
        printErrLog("pthread_create ", " monitor thread create failed");
        return(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    closelog();
    pthread_join(monitor_thread, NULL);
    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

int initIni() {
    config_init(&cfg);
    /* Read the file. If there is an error, report it and exit. */
    if (!config_read_file(&cfg, ini_file)) {
        root = config_root_setting(&cfg);

        /* Add some settings to the configuration. */
        group = config_setting_add(root, PATH_SEC, CONFIG_TYPE_GROUP);
        setting = config_setting_add(group, INSTALLED_PATH_KEY, CONFIG_TYPE_STRING);
        config_setting_set_string(setting, installed_path);
        setting = config_setting_add(group, LOG_PATH_KEY, CONFIG_TYPE_STRING);
        config_setting_set_string(setting, log_file);
        setting = config_setting_add(group, ERR_LOG_PATH_KEY, CONFIG_TYPE_STRING);
        config_setting_set_string(setting, err_log_file);
        setting = config_setting_add(group, COMMAND_LOG_PATH_KEY, CONFIG_TYPE_STRING);
        config_setting_set_string(setting, command_log_file);


        group = config_setting_add(root, CONFIG_SEC, CONFIG_TYPE_GROUP);
        setting = config_setting_add(group, UPDATE_FREQ_KEY, CONFIG_TYPE_INT);
        config_setting_set_int(setting, DEFAULT_FREQ);
        /* Write out the new configuration. */
        if (!config_write_file(&cfg, ini_file))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error while writing file.\n");
            printErrLog("initIni ", "Error while writing file");
            config_destroy(&cfg);
            return(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

    }
    else {
        config_setting_t *s = config_lookup(&cfg, CONFIG_SEC);
        config_setting_lookup_int(s, UPDATE_FREQ_KEY, &updateSec);
    }

    if (updateSec < MIN_FREQ)
        updateSec = MIN_FREQ;
    else if (updateSec > MAX_FREQ)
        updateSec = MAX_FREQ;
    config_destroy(&cfg);
    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void printLog(BYTE * title, BYTE * value) {
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    fp = fopen(log_file, "a+");
    fprintf(fp, "%s  %s\n", title, value);
    fflush(fp);
    fclose(fp);
}

void printIntLog(BYTE * title, int value) {
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    fp = fopen(log_file, "a+");
    fprintf(fp, "%s  %d\n", title, value);
    fflush(fp);
    fclose(fp);
}

void getStartTime() {
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    fp = fopen(time_file, "r");
    memset(mTimeStamp, '\0', sizeof(mTimeStamp));
    fgets(mTimeStamp, 5, fp);
    fclose(fp);
}

int getTASInfo() {
    BYTE *information = NULL;
    BYTE *information2 = NULL;

    asprintf(&information, "%s%s%s%s%s%s%d%s%s%s", VERSION, ";", BUILD, ";", PROTOCOL_VERSION, ";",
            mStatus, ";", mTimeStamp, ";");
    asprintf(&information2, "%s%s%s%s%s%s%d%s%x%x%x%x%s", VERSION, ";", BUILD, ";", PROTOCOL_VERSION, ";",
                mStatus, ";", mTimeStamp[0], mTimeStamp[1], mTimeStamp[2], mTimeStamp[3],";");
    printLog("TAS info ->", information2);

    return 0;
}


int getOSName() {
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    BYTE buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    BYTE *tmp = NULL;

    TRY {
        if ((fp = popen("uname", "r")) == NULL) {
            THROW (CMD_NOT_FND);
        }
        else {
            if (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp) == NULL)
                THROW (CMD_NOT_FND);
        }
    }
    CATCH (CMD_NOT_FND) {
        buffer[0] = 'n';
        buffer[1] = '/';
        buffer[2] = 'a';
        buffer[3] = '\0';
        printErrLog("OS name ->", "command not found");
    }
    FINALLY {
        pclose(fp);
        //printf("OS name length %d\n", strlen(buffer));
    }
    ETRY;

    tmp = strrchr(buffer, '\n');

    if (tmp)
        *tmp = ';';
    printf("OS name : %s\n", buffer);
    printLog("OS name ->", buffer);

    return 0;
}

void signal_callback_handler(int signum, siginfo_t *siginfo, void *context) {

    if (signum == SIGTERM) {
        clearData();
    }
    exit(signum);
}

void monitor_handler(void *arg) {
    static_flag = 1;
    struct timespec outtime;
    struct timeval now;
    int ret = 0;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&monitor_lock);
    while (!getStopFlag()) {

        getOSName();
        gettimeofday(&now, NULL);
        outtime.tv_sec = now.tv_sec + updateSec;
        outtime.tv_nsec = now.tv_usec * 1000;
        ret = pthread_cond_timedwait(&monitor_condition, &monitor_lock, &outtime);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&monitor_lock);
    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

Comment: This call `pthread_detach(monitor_thread);` does not make sense at all, as the thread to detach already had been joined. There is nothing to detach any more. Also due to this the call might invoke the infamous Undefined Behaviour. Just remove it.

Comment: Two calls to wait on a condition and no call to signal one? Please show the full code. As it stands the code does make no sense.

Comment: From the specifications (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cond_timedwait.html) to `pthread_cond_timedwait()`: "*[EPERM]
    The mutex type is PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK or the mutex is a robust mutex, and the current thread does not own the mutex.*" So who else is playing with the mutex? Again, please show the full code involved. You might want to cut it down to a MCVE: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hi alk, I remove pthread_detach but the issue still apears. I also update my code below, it's exact the code I use now when the issue appear.

Comment: The thread function is defined wrongly: `void monitor_handler(void *arg)` should be `void * monitor_handler(void *arg)`. The compiler should warn you on this. Take compiler warnings seriously.

Comment: Hi Alk, Thanks for the debug. But the issue is still there. Are there any clue for this issue?

Comment: Now the issue has a little bit different. It can pass the lock but won't do the stuff in the while loop after few times. Seems like a dead lock, but the pthread_mutex_unlock return 0.

Comment: Also the code seems to be using `info_lock` *before* properly initialising it. You really should add error checking to *all* relevant function calls.

Comment: Hi alk, I have initial info_lock before using it. I'll put more message at all function to check. Thanks.

Comment: The code you show does not initialise ìnfo_lock` *before* it's usage, but afterwards, inside `initThread()`.

Comment: Hi alk, I have modify the code after and initial it before I use it. Sorry for not updating it. Also, I try remove the mutex lock and info_lock, but it still the same issue.

Comment: Hi Alk, I had one more thing to mention. Event I remove all lock and cond_timedwait and used sleep function. The monitor_handler will still hang, so maybe there is something wrong about pthread in Freebsd.

Comment: Which command (including all options) do you use to compile this?

Comment: CC      = gcc48; 

MACHINE = x86_64;

MAIN_OBJECTS = $(MAIN_SOURCES:%.c=%.o);

LIB_OBJECTS = $(LIB_SOURCES:%.c=%.o);

LDFLAGS = -pthread -lpthread -lconfig; 

$(CC) -lm -o release/64bit/$@.$(MACHINE) \
                $(MAIN_OBJECTS) $(LIB_OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

```
for (x = sysconf(_SC_OPEN_MAX); x > 0; x--) {
        close(x);
    }
```

The code above is the point the system go wrong, it cannot be used in FreeBSD.
You need to write it into like below

```
/* close all descriptors */
    for (i = getdtablesize(); i >= 0; --i)
    {
        close(i);
    }

    /* Route I/O connections */

    /* Open STDIN */
    i = open("/dev/null", O_RDWR);

    /* STDOUT */
    dup(i);

    /* STDERR */
    dup(i);
```